# Cannot access participant tracks with twilio video

Tags: twilio

I'm trying to implement a 2-person video call using the twilio video api. I can't seem to access the audio/video tracks for any participants, either already in teh room or through the participantConnected callback. The code in question, where I try to access the tracks from a newly joined participant is:

```
Twilio.Video.connect(token, {name:room_name}).then(function(room) {
  console.log('Successfully joined a Room:');
  //console.log(room);
  room.on('participantConnected', function(participant) {
    console.log('A remote Participant connected:');
    console.log(participant.sid);
    participant.tracks.forEach(track => {
      //This does not get added and the console.log doesn't fire.
      console.log('adding track');
      document.getElementById('videoRow').appendChild(track.attach());
    });
  });
});
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found [examples](https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-js/blob/865fb51e9d363e6c6ee6406c7df28e2582888f9f/quickstart/src/index.js) that show how to add participant tracks.